# Is there free website which can insert handwritten math formulae?

Tags: math

MathType http://www.dessci.com/v/prod/mtw/6/mtow/mthome can insert handwritten math formulae.

Is there free website which can insert handwritten math formulae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Infty Project](http://www.inftyproject.org/en/download.html).  There seems to be a free version that you might be able to make use of.

There is also some additional discussion on this topic at: [OCR lib for math formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570220/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas)